# Is there a way to launch the stock Home Launcher (even if it isn't currently set to 'default')?

Tags: android

I'm curious how one goes about launching the stock Android Home Launcher if the device has an alternate Home application that has been selected as default.

Currently I use

```
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

But this only works if the default launcher is the Android launcher.  What I need is a way to launch the Android launcher regardless of what application the user has set up as their native Home.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you could do it if you know the package name of the launcher app on the device with `ComponenetName.unflattenFromString(packageName)` But I think this is not a real solution because not all devices will have a "default" launcher with the same package name I suspect.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one chimed in, but this is a solution that I found works.

The only problem is that you need to specify some portion of the package name that you're looking for (because presumably you're doing this when there is more than one application that has registered itself as HOME).

So the code beneath handles all the devices I've tested but obviously is in no way future proof.

```
     void getDefaultLauncher() {    

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
        final List<ResolveInfo> list = ((PackageManager)getPackageManager()).queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);      


        //String className = null;
        for(ResolveInfo ri : list){
            Log(TAG,"FOUND NATIVE LAUNCH ACTIVITY " + ri.activityInfo.packageName);


                 if(ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.lge") ||
                 ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("android") || 
                 ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("motorola.homescreen")  || 
                 ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("htc.launcher") ){

                startSpecificActivity(ri);
                return;
            }
        }

        Log(TAG,"DIDN'T FIND MATCHING HOME APP");       
    }




 public void startSpecificActivity(ResolveInfo launchable) {

     ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;

     ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,   activity.name);

    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);
    startActivity(i);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void goHome() {
try {   
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    List<ResolveInfo> lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    if (!lst.isEmpty()) {
       for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : lst) {
           if ("com.my.package".equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName)) continue; 
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
           startActivity(intent);         
           }
    }       
} catch (Throwable t) {
    L.g().log(t);
}
}
```